# How to store a value of the form 2.00 in database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP and I want to store a value 2.00 in database, but it is storing only 2 in database, I used datatype int, double, float, decimal, but none works.

Comment: Isn't 2 and 2.00 like exactly the same? Or do you want to preserve the accuracy of the number aswell?

Comment: `int` will not store fractional numbers. As for the others `2 === 2.00` so it depends on how you look at/display the data. Try `2.01` and see what happens.

Comment: How do you know it isn't storing your value correctly in the database? how are you checking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `Decimal (10,2)`.

You can adjust the scale and precision to fit the needs of the numbers you need to store

For example: `decimal(5,2)` is a number that has 3 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal

Answer (score 0):

You can also use FLOAT (4 octets) or DOUBLE (8 octets) to store decimal values.

Here, FLOAT coulb be recommended (because you use small numbers)

Answer (score 0):

**2 == 2.00** in **math**. So if you're trying to represent a currency, you should just add .00 in the end (using a simple procedure). Though if you store 2.01 it should be kept like that, in that case **float/double** will do the case. If you want a better precision (fixed) you should go for **decimal(n+k, k)** where n+k is the entire size and k the scale. (50,208 has n+k = 5 and k = 3).

If you want to add those .00 in php you should just proceed as following:

```
If (($number - (int)$number) != 0)
    $number = $number . ".00";
```

In this way you'll obtain a string containing "N.00" in the case of having a natural number.

Comment: <painful /> Why not use number_format() or money_format() instead of this unwieldy concatenation

Comment: True it's painful, but it is quite straightforward, enough to make the OP understand what's happening. Indeed number_format() or money_format() are the best pick for the solution, but in this way OP will get a grasp of WHAT SHOULD be done in these cases using just the knowledge he has.